# Spring-Cloud "Pre" ZUUL Filter

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

We have a ZUUL "Pre" Filter which checks for some condition and returns the default response by itself when a particular API (/abc) is called. When the condition is failed we are returning the response from the API.

The API is available in a service which is registered to Eureka.

**Problem**: The default response is getting returned to the client but the request is also send to the service, basically the API /abc is also getting called, we do not want the API to be called. How should we go about this.

Let me know if you need any details or code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: yes more details or code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `setSendZuulResponse(false)` in the current context. This should not route the request onto the api. You could also `removeRouteHost()` from the context, which would achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

In run() method of your custom ZuulFilter you can place following statement to avoid processing the request further and immediately return the error JSON:

this.setFailedRequest("Custom zuul filter has some error.", 401);